# Making ModelState Persistent, but not too persistent

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

Rather than a quick fix I'm more just wondering what others are doing.

The problem is that I am using ModelState for error/validation reporting to the user, but when I use a RedirectToAction(), the ModelState is lost.  To overcome this I've added some code to our base controller (that all other controllers inherit), in the override of OnActionExecuting I've added:

```
if (TempData["ModelState"] != null && !ModelState.Equals(TempData["ModelState"]))
    ModelState.Merge((ModelStateDictionary)TempData["ModelState"]);
```

And in the override of OnActionExecuted I've added:

```
TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;
```

The problem with this is it means some error messages can be displayed on the wrong pages.  I just run a `ModelState.clear()` at the start of actions I know will want to override/correct the current errors but there are cases where it is never cleared and errors show up in weird places.

How do other people handle this? any ideas welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the solution mentioned here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx

in Point 13 (Use PRG Pattern for Data Modification).

It looks fairly similar to what you are doing but using Action Filters and I haven't noticed any error messages on the wrong pages as of yet.

Comment: I found the `if (filterContext.Result is ViewResult)` part did not work as my result was always null, but took that out and it worked like a charm.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do that, I would use caching and store the modelstate in a cache (maybe session) using a key combination (session/controller/action). Have it expire after 2 minutes.

This way you'er not trying to reuse modelstate that could possibly have been written by some other action and you dont have to worry about "Is this the right modelview?"

You can then either create an attribute to apply to each method you wish to reload the modelstate for, or just do it automatically from the base controller based on the route.